# Need to get a Substring under a string

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I need to get a String which is under a Specific string.

```
$string = 'Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 13' 
ipconfig | ForEach-Object{if($_ -match $string){Select-String -AllMatches 'IPv4 Address' | Out-File C:\Temp\Avi\found.txt}}
```

For example, I need to get the IPv4 address under Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 13.

> ```
> Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:
>
>    Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
>    Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::34f2:d41c:3889:452e%21
>    IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.20.10.2
>    Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.240
>    Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 172.20.10.1
>
> Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 13:
>
>    Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
>    Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::b946:1464:9876:9e03%29
>    IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.137.1
>    Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
>    Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
> ```

Comment: take a look at the output of  `Get-Help *Net*` for the native Posh5+/Win10 cmdlets to get that info. they do NOT exist on win7ps5.1, but for that you can use `Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration`.

Answer (score 1):

Like Lee alludes to, you really don't want to use ipconfig for this, it's *much* easier to work with the Powershell native commands. Eg. to get the IPv4 addresses for the interfaces "Ethernet 8" and "Ethernet 10" you could use something like this:

```
$NetworkInterfaces = @(
    "Ethernet 10"
    "Ethernet 8"
)
foreach ($Interface in $NetworkInterfaces) {
    Get-NetIPAddress -InterfaceAlias $Interface -AddressFamily IPv4 |
        Select-Object InterfaceAlias,IPAddress 
}
```

which in my case returns this:

```
InterfaceAlias IPAddress
-------------- ---------
Ethernet 10    169.254.157.233
Ethernet 8     169.254.10.64
```

Comment: can i talk you into wrapping your line after the pipe? pretty please? [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey If you mean like my edit, yes you can! I actually prefer it that way and usually format it like that, I must've been a bit hasty here.

Comment: Hi , thanks for your suggestions, but main idea here is to get the string. I have given ipconfig just as just as an example.

Answer (score 0):

If you are bound and determine to parse this as text you can use a regex to do so.

```
$a = ipconfig | Select-String 'IPv4.*\s(?<ip>(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3})'
$a.matches[0].groups["ip"].value

10.11.12.13
```

This uses the regex matching of Select-String to find the matches as named groups, save them as a matchinfo object, then output to screen. Regex details can be found [here](https://regex101.com/r/0Tzdoj/1).

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to combine strings into one and then split it using a regular expression.

```
$s = "Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 13"
$k = "IPv4 Address"

$part = (ipconfig) -join "`n" -split "(?<=\n)(?=\S)" | Where-Object { $_.StartsWith($s) }

$part.Split("`n") |
    Where-Object { $_.TrimStart().StartsWith($k) } |
    ForEach-Object { $_.Split(":", 2)[1].Trim() }
```

Comment: Hi , Thanks for your input... it works as expected.